# how to insert data from DropDownList to database asp C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

this code give me null in database

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fk_CatID", DropDownListCategory.SelectedItem.Value);
```

this code give me null in database

```
string queryCategory = "select CatName from CategoryItemsTBL";
DataTable dtCategory = GetDataCategory(queryCategory);
DropDownListCategory.DataSource = dtCategory;
DropDownListCategory.DataTextField = "CatName";
DropDownListCategory.DataValueField = "CatName";
DropDownListCategory.DataBind();
```

Comment: show your full code. what you get in DropDownListCategory.SelectedItem.Value

Comment: It's impossible to say what's wrong with your code without more information. Have a lock at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
What's the value of `DropDownListCategory.SelectedItem.Value`?

Comment: Have you tried `DropDownListCategory.SelectedValue` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fk_CatID", DropDownListCategory.SelectedValue);
```

and before that, verify the selected value is not null

like

```
string s=DropDownListCategory.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: this give first item in the list only

Comment: are you handling DropDownListCategory- OnSelectedIndexChanged event?? and also verify which item you selected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **insert** the data, write **Insert** query rather than select.

If you want  to **select** the data... you can validate as follows.,

```
 using(SqlDataReader reader=cmd.ExecuteReader())
 {
   if(reader.Hasrows)
   {
     while(reader.Read())
     {
     //We can do validation like this
     ClassnameObj.YourLabelName=reader.IsDBNull(0)?null:reader.GetString(0);
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try

> cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fk_CatID", DropDownListCategory.SelectedValue);